# Assigning Virtual Machine a private IP address as if an independent host in LAN

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtual-machine, ip-address

I am using an Ubuntu virtual machine. I would like my VM to be in the same LAN as my actual host machine (a wireless laptop). To be reflected as if its a completely separate host. Is this possible, if so how should I go about editing the settings?

Comment: In the Virtualizing APP (VMware or other), set the LAN settings of the Guest machine to be a Bridged Network. Restart the Guest. Now it has an IP from your router on the very same Subnet as the Host (but a different IP address).

Answer (score 0):

If you are in VirtualBox/VMware you are looking for bridged networking. It allows a VM to directly connect your router.

First click the VM > Settings > Network and set Attached to "Bridged adapter".

Now to change private IP address of Ubuntu VM, boot it and open terminal. Run `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` to open The file in name or in any of your liked editor like gedit or Vim.

Then find these:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

And populate with settings:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address private_ip
netmask subnet_mask
gateway router_or_gateway_ip
dns-nameservers dns_1 dns_2
```

Reboot and then your VM will be visible in LAN. You can use `ifconfig` to see IP address and other network configuration for VM.